# ERROR: Named volume "postgres:/data/postgres:rw" is used in service "postgres" but no declaration was found in the volumes section

Tags: docker-compose, microservices

i am trying to build micro service project.
and i am getting this error when i am trying to run my docker_compose file:

```
ERROR: Named volume "postgres:/data/postgres:rw" is used in service "postgres" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.
```

this is my docker_compose file :

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: amigoscode
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
```

any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the relative path, this would work. Either use a relative path or a fixed one!

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: amigoscode
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
      - ./pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: and the network `postgres ` should be already available to make it work!

Comment: this error went away when i used this code, but i got new error dear

Comment: ERROR: Service "postgres" uses an undefined network "postgres"

Comment: That's what I meant, you have to create that network using docker CLI https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/#usage or either remove it if you don't need it!